# You heard me! (expression)

Tags: expressions, pejorative-language

What's some alternatives of saying "You heard me" while snapping back at someone (in informal and formal situations both) ?
Can I say "You heard it"?

Also in a formal setting when dealing with jerks how to say it properly so the expression has some meaning and weight.

Comment: "Did I stutter?"

Comment: Why deal with jerks at all in a formal setting. You don't want to join their number.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you shouldn't say "You heard it". It's just not normally used. 
To answer your second question, "You heard me" is quite impassioned. The reason why you might not say it in a formal situation is not because it's an specifically informal phrase in and of itself, but because it is highly emotive. There is no reason why you can't say it in a formal situation, aside from the fact that it is quite a 'strong' reaction. If that is what you're going for, I think it's fine! In any case, you could also say "I believe I made my point quite clear", or some variation of that.

Answer (score 0):

For the fomal setting: "I believe I explained myself quite adequately, for anyone with the wit to understand it and the courtesy to listen."

Comment: This explains the meaning of the expression, but surely it isn't suggested as an alternative?! There's no way to say a twenty word sentence snappily!

Comment: Yeah I agree. And in an informal setting? Any short and 'with weight' expressions to get the other person back to his or her senses?

Comment: In westerns, they usually slap 'em to get them babbling idiots back to their senses. Then, in later years, people slapped babies to make em sad that they were born. But you want something weighty ans snappy? I'm'a slap you! Short, weighty, and possibly likely to get you called to HR. But why do you *want* to be so mean? Why can't you actually ask for nice ways to get your point across?

Comment: @medica Haha very funny. Well when the other person is 'lying' you can't be nice, now can you?

Comment: @Arrowfar - you know the saying, hold your friends close, and your enemies closer. You do that with good will, not bad.